# How to handle 'Underscore Line' within the 'p' Element

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-2.0

How to handle the underscores in p tags. Here is the code which I'm working. Can anyone help me to overcome this issue.

**INPUT XML:** and **XSLT CODE:**
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/a9HjZX/1

**INPUT XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<p>Number of Shares: _______</p>
<p>__________ Name of Company.</p>
<p>Number of Shares: _______Type of Stock: ________________</p>
<p>Certificate No: __________Company.</p>
</root>
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>
    <p>Number of Shares: <inline-supplementary-material content-type="7_sld">_______</inline-supplementary-material></p>
    <p><inline-supplementary-material content-type="10_sld">__________</inline-supplementary-material> Name of Company.</p>
    <p>Number of Shares: <inline-supplementary-material content-type="7_sld">_______</inline-supplementary-material>Type of Stock: <inline-supplementary-material content-type="16_sld">________________</inline-supplementary-material></p>
    <p>Certificate No: <inline-supplementary-material content-type="10_sld">__________</inline-supplementary-material> Company.</p>
</root>
```

**XSLT CODE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="root">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="GetNoOfOccurance">
    <xsl:param name="String"/>
    <xsl:param name="SubString"/>
    <xsl:param name="Counter" select="0" />
    <xsl:variable name="sa" select="substring-after($String, $SubString)" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$sa != '' or contains($String, $SubString)">
            <xsl:call-template name="GetNoOfOccurance">
                <xsl:with-param name="String"    select="$sa" />
                <xsl:with-param name="SubString" select="$SubString" />
                <xsl:with-param name="Counter"   select="$Counter + 1" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$Counter" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p[parent::*]">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:variable name="num">
            <xsl:call-template name="GetNoOfOccurance">
                <xsl:with-param name="String" select="."/>
                <xsl:with-param name="SubString" select="'_'"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
.............
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: You should add your existing XML and XSLT code to your post as code snipped as well so that they stay available in the future even if xsltfiddle disappears. You can leave that link there for convenience anyway of course.

Comment: @JoelBodenmann Added example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `analyze-string` (in XSLT 3) or `xsl:analyze-string` (in XSLT 2), here is the XSLT 3 example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="p[matches(., '_+')]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="analyze-string(., '_+')" mode="match"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="*:match" mode="match">
        <inline-supplemental-material content-type="{string-length()}_sld">{.}</inline-supplemental-material>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/a9HjZX/2

If you expect the `p` to have child elements you might need to match on text nodes:

```
<xsl:template match="p[matches(., '_+')]//text()">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="analyze-string(., '_+')" mode="match"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*:match" mode="match">
    <inline-supplemental-material content-type="{string-length()}_sld">{.}</inline-supplemental-material>
</xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/a9HjZX/3

Comment: Thank you! It will work if other element have this case except 'p'? Moreover under 'p' element also we have other element like 'bold' & 'italic' etc. In this case will not be work.

Comment: @Umaima, you will need to clarify your requirements then and provide more details on the possible input structure. The above matches only `p` elements with `_` contents but it assumes basically the `p` has no child elements, as in your input sample. If the structure is more complex you need to explain that better, in particular if you expect a sequence of `_` to be contained in a single parent element or even in adjacent siblings.

Comment: Here below are the modified example. But 'named-content' and 'bold' element could be any parent element

Comment: <named-content content-type="new" specific-use="tbody"><bold>_____ light industry</bold></named-content>

Comment: <p content-type="continued">City: _______________________ State: <inline-supplementary-material content-type="rt"/></p>

Comment: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3Mvnt3Z/1

Comment: Consider to edit your question and to provide any code samples there in a formatted way. Also explain which output you want.

Comment: You can treat updated example: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3Mvnt3Z/1

Comment: Posting a link to a fiddlre doesn't explain or specify which output you want.

Comment: I have added expected output in the comment please visit this link https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93dFKa4/1

Comment: @Umaima, your question talks about `p` elements but if you want to handle other elements the same you can change the template's match pattern to `<xsl:template match="root/*[matches(., '_+')]//text()">` instead of `match="p[matches(., '_+')]//text()"`. But you would better edit your question and describe more precisely what input variations and wanted output you have.

Comment: Thank you so much and will let you know after testing as suggested.